# Automatically add a .gitlab-ci.yml file in CI/CD configuration file Settings

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, checkmarx, devsecops

I'm completely new with GitLab and I have a scenario where I need to automatically add a .gitlab-ci.yml file to all the project repositories, in order to trigger the pipeline for vulnerability scan in Checkmarx.

I found that we can manually add a path file in a repository by going through the project settings> CI/CD> General Pipelines>[CI/CD configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5WyB.png) .

This is only doable per project repository, but in a scenario where I have more than 100 projects, is there a way to automate and have the .gitlab-ci.yml file set upon the creation of a project repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 3 possibilities to enforece a common/shared CI config file:

1. [Edit Project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#edit-project) and set the `ci_config_path` value.
2. [Create File in Repository REST API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#create-new-file-in-repository).

In both those cases, you might need to wrap a call to the respective API a loop that iterates through all groups and subgroups first, to find all projects and their IDs, see:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-subgroups
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-projects

Or, brute-forcely iterate up from project ID `1` to a known high ID.

---

3. Another alternative is to configure a [compliance framework](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#compliance-frameworks) and use the GraphQL API to assign that framework to projects.

Comment: Hello Katrin, appreciate it and thanks for your feedback! I'll look into these options.